# "/dev/vda1" is 100% full

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a problem with Ubuntu 16.04.2, that the server is full. This is because of the "vda1" that uses 100% of the disk:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            991M     0  991M   0% /dev
tmpfs           201M  5.7M  195M   3% /run
/dev/vda1       9.7G  9.7G     0 100% /
```

I have checked for log files, but none of the files in `/var/log` is nearly big enough.

Searching for big files with `find / -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;`
 gives a couple of big files, but nearly big enough that it should be full:

```
-r-------- 1 root root 128T Aug 14 10:18 /proc/kcore
find: ‘/proc/5938/task/5938/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/5938/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 512M Aug 14 10:17 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 512M Aug 14 09:31 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
-rw------- 1 root root 204M Aug 14 10:16 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
```

I have tried commands like `sudo apt autoremove` to remove old packages, but the command cannot be run because of no space left on device. The same goes for `ncdu` which I cannot install because of full space.

Comment: 10 GiB really isn’t a lot. You’re only searching for big files. Might well be small(er) files that are to blame. Use `du -xhd1 /` or (if available) `ncdu -x /` to start exploring where space is used.

Comment: Not all files are visible if the file was deleted but is still open. Did you try to reboot? Try also in `/` to run `du -s * | sort -nr | head`.

Comment: Thanks for that command @DanielB. I can see that the www-folder actually uses 3.9GB of space. So it might just be possible that the system and log files uses around 6GB of space? I have tried to reboot yes, actually the mySQL-server had problems starting after that, maybe related to space issues.